# Why am I getting gibberish content using Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, mechanize

Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) returns complete garbage (like ðäD=°"lc*Ñ2\7 õä1û¼Âc{oî´lDNöÓ8ß5o*F2Õ©-õ£z§2ÜÝ1,³íäþwÉ¯ÓQÞÆÁS¿IZDKÁ»,ËmÅS1r4!°s,¥4Jl;\J~í2¼) after retrieving a page.

I am sure it is related to the particular web server from which I am trying to download.  I need plain html.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize;

$url = 'http://www.example.com/brands/';

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$page = $mech->content();
print "$page\n";
```

I guess this could be an encoding issue.

Any clues on how to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: I bet you're getting gzipped data from the server. What happens if you try `print $mech->res->decoded_content;` ?

Comment: Show us the response headers. (The part of `$mech->res->as_string` before the junk)

Comment: just in case, a please provide your version of WWW::Mechanize. (`perl -e'use WWW::Mechanize 99'` will include the version in an error message)

Comment: I'm using version 1.66.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server may be sending compressed content.  Try:

```
$page = $mech->response->decoded_content;
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't help.  The page produces a web page viewable with a browser (and "view source" works).  I wouldn't think a browser could handle compressed content, would it?

Comment: Yes, gzip compression is a standard HTTP feature. It's going to be difficult to debug by making guesses. Look at the response headers you get and see if there are any clues about the encoding or character sets.

Comment: Most browsers (certainly all of the major ones) handle compressed content just fine.

Comment: OK, guys, thanks for the help.  I never knew that. The headers show content encoding as gzip, so I guess that's it.

Comment: I try: #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize;
$url = 'http://www.example.com/brands/';

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
my $content = $mech->response->decoded_content;

print "$content\n";

Comment: #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
    use WWW::Mechanize;
    $url = 'http://www.example.com/brands/';

    $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    $mech->get($url);
    my $content = $mech->response->decoded_content;

    print "$content\n";
This still doesn't work for my encoded data.  It returns a "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 9." for the site with suspected compressed content, though it works well for others.  Really mystified.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent days hunting this down. Mechanize sends a header claiming it does compression, so the server responds with compressed data, which Mechanize doesn't know it has to decode.

The issue manifested itself with error "Status read failed:"

If you force compression by installing and using WWW::Mechanize::GZip, all will work fine.